# Graph API photo return picture with question mark

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a larger version of a photo's picture by calling this:

https://graph.facebook.com/101510465867446xxx/picture.

Sometimes I get a proper large picture but I mostly got a picture with a large question mark.

I must be missing something here. Can somebody give me a clue as to what am I doing wrong? Yes I can call the photo API to get more info including the different sizes and source of the photo, but I want to minimize more http call to the server to speed thing sup.

Comment: can you tell me url of picture with question mark?

Comment: Hmm, it's a private photo shared to me by my friends, not sure how useful it is to put the complete link here. I am pretty sure I am allowed to see the pic.

Answer (score 4):

For large picture use following to get public picture url

https://graph.facebook.com/xxyyzz/picture?type=large

for user specific pic use `access_token` with url

https://graph.facebook.com/xxyyzz/picture?type=large&access_token=xyxaaa

Comment: Thanks mtariq, that's exactly what I am doing now. The "xxyyzz" is the object ID and if I don't specify the type=large then I can get the small thumbnail. However if I specify the type=large then I will get a picture of a question mark. Could it be that I am missing some permission? The photos are from my friend.

Comment: Yes, it's included by the Facebook sdk. I am using the Facebook Android sdk btw. Sorry for not making it clear earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This way of retrieving someone’s photo only works if that someone has set the privacy of their photo so that it is visible to the current user (logged in into the browser/client making the request).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm login and using a valid sesssion token. I can see the image using browser and my android fb client. I can see the small "picture" returned in the graph api feed json data thought.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar to use image of events picture.
I had several question marks, and the answer was that these events weren't public.

Sometimes, the object is private or open only to "friends of friends", so facebook restricts the access to the image.

The only "fix" is to change the object confidentiality.